# How to show playing item details in the iphone/ipad dock bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, avplayer

I make use of a `AVPlayer` to reproduce music tracks in the iPod Library.

I got the background management done, and now I can see my app icon showing in the dock bar when tapping twice the home button.
Media buttons also work fine with my app.

What I would like to do now is **to show now playing item info in the same dock bar**, as iPodMusicPlayer does.

Is it possible?

Comment: AFAIK you cant. use the ipod media player framework or scratch that feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the MediaPlayer framework:

```
#include <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:@{
                           MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist:@"Album Artist",
                            MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle:@"Album Title",
                                 MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:@"Title",
                                MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:@"Artist"
 }];
```

Comment: yeah perfect. I found it already and I was just about to answer to myself. Great Job an thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that using iOS public API's. As far as iPod Music App is considered, it is a native iOS application built in by Apple and it uses Private API's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is apple's sample code, may be this will help
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Introduction/Intro.html